# Store multidimensional array from JQuery Dropdown checklist in database in string form using loop

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, drop-down-menu, multidimensional-array

I want to store an array of checklist into a string in a database. Below this is the code in the interface which display a list of room with a dropdown checklist for each room.

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
          <!-- Apply dropdown check list to the selected items  -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){$("#<?php echo $bnum; ?>").dropdownchecklist( { width: 300 } );});
     </script>  

         <!-- This is the JQuery Dropdown checklist !-->                     
        <select id="<?php print $bnum;?>" multiple="multiple" name="dietdata[]" >
                     <option value="0"></option>

         <?php  
          //query drop-down list
         $sqlakh="select diet_id,diet_name from bmsdb.diettypes";
         $resultakh=mysql_query($sqlakh);
         while($rowsakh= mysql_fetch_array($resultakh)) { ?>
        <option  value='<?php echo $rowsakh['diet_id'].'|'.$bnum; ?>'><?php echo $rowsakh['diet_name']; ?>            
        </option>
         <?php }

}//end while ?>

</select>`
```

When I submit this form in the server side, this is what I do to extract the data from the array of the dropdown checklist:

```
      $data2 = $_POST['data2']; //total no of data
  $dietdata= $_POST['dietdata']; //diet data
  $roomlist= $_POST['data3']; //patient room number


  for($k=0; $k<=sizeof($data3); $k++){

  $dietarray= $dietdata[$k];

  $separatediet= (explode('|',$dietarray));

  $output_array[]=array("diet"=>$separatediet['0'],"room"=>$separatediet['1']);

   for($j=0; $j<=sizeof($data3); $j++){

   if($output_array[$k][room]== $roomlist[$j]){

     $rekod[$output_array[$k][room]]= $output_array[$k][diet];

    }
      }
     }print_r($rekod);
```

The `print_r` output when I submitting the form is like this:

```
Array ( [501] => 3 [502] => 4 [] => )
```

Then I extract the array using `implode` to separate the room and the diet type.

```
Array ( [0] => 2|501 [1] => 3|501 
        [2] => 3|502 [3] => 4|502 )
```

What I want is for the array to be like this. Is there any way for me to make the array to be like this, or a better structure to use?

```
Array ( [501] => 2,3) //2,3 is the diet type group together after being extracted from the array above
        [502] => 3,4 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're keeping all the code up to the point where you're imploding to generate your final array:

```
Array ( [0] => 2|501 [1] => 3|501 
    [2] => 3|502 [3] => 4|502 )
```

You could create the array you're asking for like this:

```
$out = array(); // The final output array

foreach ($your_array as $item) {
  $vals = explode('|', $item);
  if (!isset($out[$item[1]])) $out[$item[1]] = array();
  $out[$item[1]][] = $item[0];
}

foreach ($out as &$item) {
  $item = implode(',', $item);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help i was able to generate the array that i want. By adjusting a little bit of your code i able to produce the array that i want which i something like this 

'Array ( [501] => 2,3,4 [502] => 3,4 [503] => 5,6 )'

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code. Which generata output like this

```
Array ( [501] => 2,3,4 [502] => 3,4 [503] => 5,6 )
```

Thanks to Hibiscus for your help.

```
    $out = array(); // The final output array

    foreach ($status as $item) {

    $vals = explode('|', $item);

    if (!isset($out[$vals[1]])) $out[$vals[1]] = array();
    $out[$vals[1]][] = $item[0];
    }

    $item=array();
    foreach ($out as &$item) 
    {
         $item = implode(',', $item);
    }
         $diet = array();
         $data3 = $_POST['data3'];

    for($h=0; $h<=$data2; $h++)
    { 
         $data3 = $_POST['data3']; //patient bnum
         $data3 = $data3[$h];//bnum
         if(!empty($out[$data3]))
    {
         $diet[$data3] = $out[$data3];
    }
 }  print_r($diet);
```